# Tv shows depicting magic and superpowers

Tags: halal-haram, tv

Is it okay to view tv shows/movie that include elements of **fictional** magic, myths and supernatural abilities?

Note that, magic shown is by no means "**dark**" or implies anything contrary/offensive to Islam. By dark I mean the tv show by no means call upon the devils, jinns, etc etc. If it does happen, surely the tv show portrays it as evil and frames the person doing it as the villain.

In addition, the tv show I am referring to enforces a lot of Islamic values such as respecting and loving your family no matter what, seeing the good in people, sacrificing one's life for the sake of others...etc etc etc.

Comment: FYI magic doesn't need to be dark in order to be haram.

Comment: @Medi1Saif...if you're talking about fictional magic which is seen in movies and tv, there's no way it can be haram, given it's already fictional and false. If you're talking about magic which is performed in the streets as a means to mock people intelligence or fool them...to thinking something that is not really happening...then YEA I agree that kinda magic is HARAM.

Comment: Magic in TV and movies are actually explained a lot from science and stuff...that's where "sci-fi fantasy" genre emerge from